# How to define a proper objective function in python for the optimization solver

Tags: python, function, optimization, lambda, scipy-optimize-minimize

I need to define an optimization objective function for Scipy SLSQP slover.
The difficulties is that the number of independent variables in my objective function is not fixed. I was trying to use the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import scipy.special as sc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
L10, L20 = 2.3, 2.3
# one step look ahead
# Eindf = [1116, 1160, 841, 1116]
# Dindf = [44, 861, 275]
# Ldf = [4.2, 5.2, 4.8, 4.4]
Eindf = [1116, 1160, 841]
Dindf = [44, 861]
Ldf = [4.2, 5.2, 4.8]

R10, R20 = 0.1803, 0.1803
Rfc1, Rfc2 = R10 + 0.003, R20 + 0.0

if Rfc1 > Rfc2:
    w1 = (Rfc1 * np.exp((Rfc1-Rfc2)) + Rfc1) / (Rfc2 + np.exp((Rfc1-Rfc2))*Rfc1 + Rfc1)
    w2 = Rfc2 / (Rfc2 + np.exp((Rfc1-Rfc2))*Rfc1+ Rfc1)
else:
    w1 = ( Rfc1) / (Rfc2 + np.exp((Rfc1-Rfc2))*Rfc1+ Rfc1)
    w2 = (Rfc2 * np.exp((Rfc2-Rfc1) + Rfc2)) / (Rfc2 * np.exp((Rfc2-Rfc1))+ Rfc2 + Rfc1)

β = 0.00873 

Ratio_VtoR = 5.39
Dv_ΔL = 5.93e-7
RatioD_ΔL = 20 
Dr_ΔL = RatioD_ΔL * Dv_ΔL * Ratio_VtoR
k = (R10 * Dr_ΔL) / (Lmax - Lmin)

def alpha_beta(x):
    # a, b are params fitted for parabola functions
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
    return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(Lmin <= x, x < Lnom),
                            np.logical_and(Lnom <= x, x <= Lmax)],
                        [lambda x: a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226,
                         lambda x: b * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226, 0])

def func1(Dind): 
    crit = lambda x: (k*(w1*abs(x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(x[1]-L20))+\
                    β*Dind[0]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[0])+w2*alpha_beta(x[1]))+ β*Dind[1]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[2])+w2*alpha_beta(x[3]))+\
                      k*(w1*abs(x[2]-x[0]) + w1*abs(x[4]-x[2]) + w2*abs(x[3]-x[1])+w2*abs(x[5]-x[3])))
    return crit

def func2(Dind): 
    crit = lambda x: (k*(w1*abs(x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(x[1]-L20))+ β*Dind[1]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[2])+w2*alpha_beta(x[3]))+\
                      β*Dind[0]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[0])+w2*alpha_beta(x[1]))+\
                      k*(w1*abs(x[2]-x[0]) + w1*abs(x[4]-x[2]) + w2*abs(x[3]-x[1])+w2*abs(x[5]-x[3])))
    return crit
                     
def func(Dind):
    Cr1 = lambda x: (k*(w1*abs(x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(x[1]-L20)) +\
                     sum((β*Dind[i]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[2*i])+w2*alpha_beta(x[2*i+1])) +\
                    k*(w1*abs(x[2*(i+1)]-x[2*i]) + w2*abs(x[2*(i+1)+1]-x[2*i+1]))) for i in range(len(Dind))))                
    return Cr1

bounds = Bounds([Lmin]*2*len(Ldf), [Lmax]*2*len(Ldf))

A_mat = np.zeros((len(Ldf), 2*len(Ldf)))
for i in range(len(Ldf)):
    A_mat[i, 2*i] = 1
    A_mat[i, 2*i+1] = 1
    
linear_cons = LinearConstraint(A_mat, np.array(Ldf), (1.08 * np.array(Ldf)))

x0 = np.repeat(Ldf, 2) / 2 

res = minimize(func(Dindf), x0, method='trust-constr', constraints=linear_cons, options={'disp': 0, 'xtol':1e-5,
                'maxiter': 80, 'gtol':1e-7, 'verbose': 0}, bounds=bounds)
print(f'func:{res.x}')


res = minimize(func1(Dindf), x0, method='trust-constr', constraints=linear_cons, options={'disp': 0, 'xtol':1e-5,
                'maxiter': 80, 'gtol':1e-7, 'verbose': 0}, bounds=bounds)
print(f'func1:{res.x}')

res = minimize(func2(Dindf), x0, method='trust-constr', constraints=linear_cons, options={'disp': 0, 'xtol':1e-5,
                'maxiter': 80, 'gtol':1e-7, 'verbose': 0}, bounds=bounds)
print(f'func2:{res.x}')
```

I got outputs:

```
func:[2.30419673 2.23050723 2.52527556 2.67472855 2.52537813 2.5305927 ]
func1:[2.30460228 2.22989643 2.52506878 2.67493795 2.52505983 2.54172443]
func2:[2.30369304 2.22975576 2.52527861 2.67474766 2.52559372 2.52896126]
```

To be more clear, I have put several optimization cases. func() is a general form in order to handle an arbitrary number of independent variables. func1() and fucn2() actually are identical, I just change the order of some terms. And the structure of func1(), func2() is the same as func(). What I did not understand is why the optimization results are different?

Comment: You forgot to check `res.message` or `res.success`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I have checked the output res.success, they are all false. Can you help to give a clue on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add a larger 'maxiter', for example, 200, the res.success is True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I did not understand is why the optimization results are different?

Although the functions `func`, `func1` and `func2` are essentially equivalent, the different order of additions can cause more or less slight differences in the results (depending on the magnitude difference of the summands), leading the minimization to take somewhat different paths and finally to reach the termination tolerance at different points.

Comment: Yes, this explains the slight difference in the optimization results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined one of the functions wrong, although it's hard for me to say which is 'technically correct'. Either way, your special case function does not match what the generic function shows in the case of `len(Dind) = 4`:

```
form = ['k*(w1*abs(x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(x[1]-L20))']

for i in range(0,4):
  form.append(f'β*Dind[{i}]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[{2*i}])+w2*alpha_beta(x[{2*i+1}])) + k*(w1*abs(x[{2*(i+1)}]-x[{2*i}]) + w2*abs(x[{2*(i+1)+1}]-x[{2*i+1}]))')

print('+'.join(form))
```

This gives me:

```
crit = lambda x: k*(w1*abs(x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(x[1]-L20))+β*Dind[0]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[0])+w2*alpha_beta(x[1])) + k*(w1*abs(x[2]-x[0]) + w2*abs(x[3]-x[1]))+β*Dind[1]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[2])+w2*alpha_beta(x[3])) + k*(w1*abs(x[4]-x[2]) + w2*abs(x[5]-x[3]))+β*Dind[2]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[4])+w2*alpha_beta(x[5])) + k*(w1*abs(x[6]-x[4]) + w2*abs(x[7]-x[5]))+β*Dind[3]*(w1*alpha_beta(x[6])+w2*alpha_beta(x[7])) + k*(w1*abs(x[8]-x[6]) + w2*abs(x[9]-x[7]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for checking this. Sorry I report an error value for len(Dind), it should be 2 in the special case. I have correct this.